# React - How to Send JWT via Headers

Tags: reactjs, asp.net, api, jwt, bearer-token

I have a .NET 7 Web API which has authentication/authorization via JWT. Currently the app correctly blocks API requests without a JWT and allows them with it as tested via SwaggerUI and Postman; however, I am unable to send the request correctly via React.

`Method sending request:`

```
const getTopics = () => {
    const url = API_ROUTES.TOPICS_GET_ALL_TOPICS;
    fetch(url, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${jwt}`
      }
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(topicsFromServer => {
      console.log(topicsFromServer);
      setTopics(topicsFromServer);
    })
    .catch((error => {
      console.error(error);
    }))
  }
```

If I console log the response above, I receive the following:

```
Response {type: 'cors', url: 'https://localhost:7174/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Ftopic%2Fget-all-topics', redirected: true, status: 405, ok: false, …}
body
: 
(...)
bodyUsed
: 
false
headers
: 
Headers {}
ok
: 
false
redirected
: 
true
status
: 
405
statusText
: 
""
type
: 
"cors"
url
: 
"https://localhost:7174/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Ftopic%2Fget-all-topics"
[[Prototype]]
: 
Response
```

The response url is not an existing endpoint, but I'm guessing it is auto-generated by .NET `[Authorize]` attribute.

`Cors Policy in .NET:`

```
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("CORSPolicy", builder =>
    {
        builder
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000", "https://localhost:3000");
    });
});
```

Not sure if this helps, but this is my Swagger Gen configuration:

```
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    options.AddSecurityDefinition("auth0", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {
        In = ParameterLocation.Header,
        Name = "Authorization",
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey
    });

    options.OperationFilter<SecurityRequirementsOperationFilter>();
});
```

If there is any other info needed please let me know. Thank you!

**Edit:**

After further testing, it appears that the jwt is still not being utilized in anyway. Once a user logs into their account, a cookie is then stored in the browser (SwaggerUI) or Postman, allowing them access to the API without the JWT.

The cookie being utilized:

```
.AspNetCore.Identity.Application=ReallyLongString; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly; Expires=Fri, 31 Mar 2023 23:07:00 GMT;
```

Here is `Program.cs` in case there is an issue there:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("CORSPolicy", builder =>
    {
        builder
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000", "https://localhost:3000", "https://appname.asurestaticapps.net");
    });
});
// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    options.AddSecurityDefinition("auth0", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {
        In = ParameterLocation.Header,
        Name = "Authorization",
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey
    });

    options.OperationFilter<SecurityRequirementsOperationFilter>();
});

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
        {
            ValidateIssuer = false,
            ValidateAudience = false,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
            ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(
                Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["Jwt:Key"])
            )
        };
    });

builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<SdeResearchDbContext>();
builder.Services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<SdeResearchDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

builder.Services.AddScoped<JwtService>();

builder.Services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
{
    // Password Settings.
    options.Password.RequireDigit= true;
    options.Password.RequireLowercase= true;
    options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric= true;
    options.Password.RequireUppercase= true;
    options.Password.RequiredLength= 8;
    options.Password.RequireLowercase= true;
    options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 6;

    // User settings
    options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters =
    "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._@+!";
    options.User.RequireUniqueEmail= true;
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseCors("CORSPolicy");
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();


app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "Topic",
    pattern: "topic/*{action}"
    );

app.Run();
```

TopicController has `[Authorize]` at the top of the controller.

Comment: should headers be an array? here is how I do it in react with .net core backend.  `  try{
          const token = commonStore.token;
    
          const headers = new Headers();
            headers.append('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
          const requestOptions = {
           method: 'GET',
          headers: headers,
          };
          const attachmentData = await fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/upload/${metaData.id}`, requestOptions);`

Comment: I made the recommended changes and still get the error.

Comment: 405 means "method not allowed". Are you sure there is an endpoint under that specific url responding to a `GET` request? I don't know how your backend expects authorization, but in principle sending your header like shown in the first snippet is fine. But where is that `jwt` you are using there defined? Are you sure it as the value you expect it to have?

Comment: @derpirscher I have a .NET 7 web API and am sending the JWT when a user logs in. I just tested the frontend token in Postman and it doesn't work, but if I login via postman a cookie is added to Postman which allows access and doesn't require a token. It appears the token isn't required. I've added the Program.cs code to the **Edit** section.

Comment: Sorry, can't help you with the serverside, as I don't have any experience with that technology ...

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of react using the axios package to do the API call against a C# API endpoint using what seem to be your variable names and endpoint routes.

```
import axios from 'axios';

const getTopics = () => {
  return axios.get(API_ROUTES.TOPICS_GET_ALL_TOPICS, {
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: `Bearer ${jwt}`
    }
  }).then(response => {
    console.log(response.data);
    setTopics(response.data);
  }).catch(error => console.error(error));
};
```

Comment: I think this would definitely work; however, I made a discovery that somehow the JWT isn't being utilized at all and instead Postman and my browser (with SwaggerUI) are storing a cookie allowing them access to the API.